# Неверно работает код php, ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

Когда нажимаю на звездочку второй записи, чтобы добавить в избранное, добавляется первая.
В чем может быть проблема? вывожу через цикл while
Добавляю в избранное через js

```
function sendfav(){
                   Snackbar.show({text: 'Добавлено в избранное!', actionText: 'Закрыть!', duration: 100000});
                
                
                
                var favorites = $("#fav").serialize();
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "system/add_fav.php",
                            data: favorites,
                        });
                    }
            $('#btnfav').click(function() {
                $.post("system/add_fav.php");
                })
```

Вроде отсылаю айди верный.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<input type="hidden" name="id_post" class="form-control" maxlength="12" value="'; echo $row['id']; echo '">
```

```
   session_start();
if(isset($_POST['id_user'])){
$id_user=htmlentities(trim($_POST['id_user']));
$id_post=htmlentities(trim($_POST['id_post']));
$title_post=htmlentities(trim($_POST['title_post']));
$description_post=htmlentities(trim($_POST['description_post']));
$user_post=htmlentities(trim($_POST['user_post']));
$date_create_post=htmlentities(trim($_POST['date_create_post']));
    include 'bd.php';
$query="INSERT INTO `fav_posts` (`title_post`,`description_post`,`user_post`,`id_user`,`date_create_post`,`id_post`) VALUES('$title_post','$description_post','$user_post','$id_user','$date_create_post','$id_post') ";
$result=mysql_query($query);
    if($result==true)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: «Вроде отсылаю айди верный» — как вы это проверяете?

Comment: никак) догадки. всегда добавляется сначала первый пост в избранное. даже если на пятый нажму, добавится первый. пытаюсь понять , почему?

Comment: Ну как минимум потому что `$("#fav")` всегда будет указывать строго на первый элемент, хотя бы потому, что на странице запрещено иметь несколько элементов с одинаковым id

Comment: то есть, надо использовать this ? если да , то не могу сообразить куда его поставить.

Comment: поменял на $('.fav') и сменил id="fav" на class="fav" . но теперь первые записи не добавляются, а последняя добавляется...

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendfav(cur_this){
    Snackbar.show({text: 'Добавлено в избранное!', actionText: 'Закрыть!', duration: 100000});

    // родительский_блок(класс или id) это где находится id #fav
    var favorites = $(cur_this).closest('родительский_блок').find('#fav').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "system/add_fav.php",
        data: favorites,
    });

}

$('#btnfav').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    sendfav(this);
})
```